# Crash Reporter Logs

Tags: macos, mac

What do I do with these files that resides in `/Library/Logs/CrashReporter`?

How do I send them to Apple?

Comment: I feel like saying, print them out and mail them to Apple....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your settings, the logs are sent to Apple whenever you press Submit to Apple... when a dialog box saying "Application Name" has quit unexpectedly appears.

You can always attach the logs to bug reports (http://bugreporter.apple.com) if you believe the problem is an actual bug to do with one of Apple's products. Additionally if it's a 3rd party application that crashes, the developers tend to love getting the crash reports to help them figure out what went wrong.

If you don't have any use for the logs you can safely delete them.